# Dúvida de como exibir o nome de uma key de um dicionário

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, dicionário

É possível exibir o nome de somente uma *key* de um dicionário?
ex:

```
notas_por_materias = { "Matematica" : 7,
                       "Portugues" : 8,
                       "Historia" : 10 }
```

Consigo exibir um *print* mostrando o nome da matéria e depois a nota dela? Ex:

```
print (f"Sua nota em {Matematica}, foi de {nota_por_materias["Matematica"]}")
```

Eu consigo exibir o valor da nota, porem não consigo fazer o mesmo com o nome da matéria. Tentei passar como índice [0] e como `notas_por_materias.keys(0)`, porém sem sucesso. Sei que tem varias outras formas bem mais simples de fazer isso, porém como estou aprendendo a utilizar dicionários, gostaria de saber como exibir por meio deles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que você está fazendo não faz muito sentido. Se você sabe o que deseja imprimir então não tem porque fazer diferente do que fez, exceto que não usar essas chaves. Tem erros de sintaxe nisso também (nome da variável escrito errado, confusão entre aspas duplas e simples para separar o que é o texto e o que é a chave do dicionário, feito assim ele acha que o dicionário está encerrando o texto), fazendo tudo certo ficaria assim:

```
print (f"Sua nota em Matemática, foi de {notas_por_materias['Matematica']}")
```

Se deseja fazer em um laço, aí faria mais ou menos algum sentido em generalizar o nome da matéria, mas aí é outro problema. Um dos motivos que não faz tanto sentido assim é porque a chave é um dado escrito de uma forma muito simples pra facilitar o código e o que quer que seja impresso é algo apresentável para um ser humano, são conceitos diferentes, só nesse exemplo já vemos um problema, a chave não tem acento e o que deseja apresentar tem, fora que começa com maiúsculo o que pode não ser o desejado no texto em alguns cenários. Se quiser insistir nisso, seria algo assim:

```
for key, value in notas_por_materias.items() :
    print (f"Sua nota em {key}, foi de {value}")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/92aHaz). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/KeyOnDictionarypy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/KeyOnDictionary.py).

Comment: Consegui compreender o erro, obrigado pela ajuda!!